# C# class/methods modifiers

Tags: c#, class, methods, modifier

I'm trying to make spreadsheet with class/method modifiers. The spreadsheet itself can be located [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiXMCtUsCCDodFFXTE1rRnl1cHdIT1FFSUZMTDNuNkE), although I have some questions:

1) As I read, methods also can be `sealed`, but what's the purpose of this? Protecting method against overriding?

2) Does fields also have to be `abstract` in `abstract` class?

3) Can `virtual` method have body in defined object/class?

Comment: you can try them all and see what happen

Comment: 2) A field declaration reserves storage without opportunity to define or redefine an interaction. Overrides occur on interactions, like methods and property getters/setters. It may seem unclear at first that you can override a property, when a property can appear to be storage. If so, remember this is simply a nicety of C#; that when you declare myProp{get;set;}, it automatically creates a backing field for you, and the interaction occurs against that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: yes, exactly that; stopping a virtual method from being overridden again in a subclass

2: fields are never abstract; fields **are** implementation; nothing *has* to be abstract in an abstract class

3: yes, in that the virtual modifier is distinct from the abstract modifier. Both represent a virtual-method - the difference is *entirely* whether there is an implementation in the base class

Answer (score 3):

1. `sealed` methods [prevents further overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152049/sealed-method-in-c-sharp) down the inheritance chain. `sealed` methods also need to have override keyword.
2. Fields cannot be `abstract`. Field is a class level variable. You can't override that. Properties and methods can be `abstract`, but doesn't need to.
3. The difference between `virtual` and `abstract` methods is that virtual method has an implementation. You can override that implementation in derived class.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No - there is no such thing as abstract field, the class is abstract, meaning it cannot be instantiated but the fields defined on it are part of the layout of derived non-abstract classes.
3. Yes