# In C#, if a class or a method is not marked as sealed or virtual, what is it?

Tags: c#, .net

In other words, what's the default (if nothing is specified)?  I'm guessing the default is virtual, because you can use the "new" keyword to override a base method even when the base method has no virtual specified.  If that's the case then why do we even need a Virtual option?  Couldn't we just use Sealed when we do need to prevent further inheritance?

Comment: Without virtual specified the new keyword shadows the member and it is no longer available.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152049/sealed-method-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# methods are sealed by default -- you cannot override them without the `virtual` keyword.

The `new` keyword **hides** the method in the base class.

Here's what I mean by hiding:

```
public class HidingA
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class HidingB : HidingA
{
    public new string Get()
    {
        return "B";
    }
}

HidingA a = new HidingA();
HidingB b = new HidingB();

Console.WriteLine(a.Get()); // "A"
Console.WriteLine(b.Get()); // "B"

HidingA c = new HidingB();
Console.WriteLine(c.Get()); // "A". Since we're calling this instance of "B" an "A",    
                            //we're using the "A" implementation.
```

Now, the Virtual version!

```
public class VirtualA
{
    public virtual string Get()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class VirtualB : VirtualA
{
    public override string Get()
    {
        return "B";
    }
}
VirtualA a = new VirtualA();
VirtualB b = new VirtualB();

Console.WriteLine(a.Get()); // "A"
Console.WriteLine(b.Get()); // "B"

VirtualA c = new VirtualB();
Console.WriteLine(c.Get()); // "B". We overrode VirtualB.Get, so it's using the 
                            // "B" implementation of the method
```

So if we make a method that takes `HidingA` as a parameter and pass it an instance of a `HidingB`, we're going to get the `HidingA` implementation of the `Get` method.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39.aspx

Classes are open for inheritance unless the `sealed` keyword is specified.

Comment: I'd include a mention of the difference between `new` and `override`, but this is the most accurate answer so far.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about Classes ;)

Comment: Thank you.  So classes are virtual by default then?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "virtual" class in C#, since multiple inheritance is not allowed. Unsealed classes can be subclassed, and virtual methods within a class can be overridden in subclasses.

Comment: Sorry for more questions, but I am trying to get an in-depth understanding.  What is the connection between virtual and multiple inheritance? i.e. Why is virtual irrelevant in single inheritance?

Comment: Also, what does "hide" really mean?  If a base method gets "hidden" with the use a of the "new" keyword, does that mean the base method is gone forever?  Or is it only inaccessible within the sub class and further sub classes?

Comment: Consult your search engine of choice for an in-depth explanation of virtual base classes in languages that support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Ah ok, so "new" means that the method is a completely new method and not associated in anyway with the base method which happens to share the same name...

Answer (score 1):

`new` creates a new method (not overriding it), where as an overridden one would replace it, hence being `virtual`. As stated above by DanielM, methods are sealed by default.

This is why we need virtual:

```
   class Foo
   {
       public void Baz() { Assert("Foo.Baz"); }
   }

   class ChildOfFoo : Foo
   {
       public new void Baz() { Assert("ChildOfFoo.Baz"); }
   }

   Foo foo = new ChildOfFoo();
   foo.Baz(); // Foo.Baz
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that's asked.